# How to get sum of groups in crystal report 10?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report with for some invoices and each invoice has some lines like this :

```
invoice1 2000
     line1   300
     line2   700
     line3   500
     line4   500
invoice2 1000
     line1   300
     line2   400
     line3   300
```

Now, when I use summary for group#1, I should get 3000 as sum of group amount.
but it shows me 11000 *(4X2000)+(3X1000)* because it sums invoice lines!
what should I do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should have running total that is placed into your 'Group Footer #1'

If you right-click and select 'Edit Running Total' you should have the following:

- Field to summarize should be your value you wish to sum. I guess this is correct!
- Type of summary - should be sum
- Evaluate - 'For each record' should be selected.
- Reset - 'On change of group' should be selected and Group #1 should be chosen.

---

**Update**
In this case if the summary data appears in the source data and you a total for the whole reports change the running total to only evalute for each invoice (Group #1) and don't Reset.

**Note:** Assuming **Group #1** is on **Invoice Number** and the summary required is for the whole report

So the steps will now be:

- Field to summarize should be your value you wish to sum. I guess this is correct!
- Type of summary - should be sum
- Evaluate - '**On chnge of group**' should be selected.
- Reset - **'Never'** should be selected and Group #1 should be chosen.

Comment: @LIX, I think your datasource table has columns for both the invoice total and the individual line items.  Hence, you have 4 rows with 2000 in the invoice total column and 3 more rows with 1000 in that column.  Dog Ears suggestion (or something similiar) should do the trick.

Comment: I use CR 10 and and summary just works on details. so when I insert sum of a value of header, It just calculates sum of details, and not group value.

Comment: @LIX - In that case change the 'Evalute' to: **On change of group** and select the invoice grouping, assuming Group #1 is grouped on invoice that would be right. You'll then need to change 'Reset' to **none**