# Crystal Reports Sum of average group costs in header information

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

This has had me stumped for days now and I still don't know the best way about it.

All my records in my report are grouped by customer name and in each group footer is a series of calculations to get the costs for that customer. I have a field there called @AvgCost which gives me the average of the service costs for that group.
[image]

If I do a sum of these averages in the report footer I get a figure that is well and truly above what it should be. This is because even though the value is only showing once in the group footer, it is evaluating for every record in the group, so if my average is 100 for one group with 5 records and 50 for another with 2 records I would get a sum of 600 instead of 150.

The first condition I need to overcome is getting it to only evaluate once per group. The second is I need this to appear in the report header instead of the footer.

I thought I would be able to use the next function to only get the value once per group, but this wont let me do a summary afterwards.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd show us your formula content here.

Comment: Does this looks like your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388243/how-to-get-sum-of-groups-in-crystal-report-10

Comment: Hi @Wong, unfortunately I need this value in the report header which I cant do with a running total.

Comment: @NickJones Instead of Formula Field, consider using SQL Expression Field. You can construct a query with WHERE and GROUP BY to get the correct value.